# pandas read_csv parse foreign dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `read_csv` on a .csv file that contains a date column. The problem is that the date column is in a foreign language (romanian), with entries like:

'26 septembrie 2017'

'13 iulie 2017'

etc. How can I parse this nicely into a pandas dataframe which has a US date format?

Comment: If its just the months that are the issue , you can map onto that column to replace it with recognizable formats

Comment: Is it the same time system? Do you need to only adjust the months or do you have  to recognize  hours and minutes and adjust them to a different timezone?

Comment: Same time system, only the month names are different.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass a converter for that column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, converters={'date_column': foreign_date_converter})
```

But first you have to define the converter to do what you want. This approach uses locale manipulation:

```
def foreign_date_converter(text):
    # Resets locale to "ro_RO" to parse romanian date properly
    # (non thread-safe code)
    loc = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ro_RO')
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(text '%d %b %Y').date()
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, loc) # restores locale
    return date
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/) module.

```
import dateparser
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparser.parse)
```

Enter your date column name in `parse_dates` parameter. I'm just assuming it as `date`

You may have output like this:

```
      date
0   2017-09-26    
1   2017-07-13
```

If you want to change the format use `strftime` [strftime](http://strftime.org/)

```
df['date'] = df.date.dt.strftime(date_format = '%d %B %Y')
```

output:

```
      date
0   26 September 2017
1        13 July 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to simply use 12 times the `str.replace(old, new)` function.

It is not pretty but if you just built the function:

```
def translater(date_string_with_exatly_one_date):
    date_str = date_string_with_exatly_one_date
    date_str = date_str.replace("iulie", "july")
    date_str = date_str.replace("septembrie", "september")
    #do this 10 more times with the right translation
    return date_str
```

Now you just have to call it for every entry. After that you can handle it like a US date string. This is not very efficient but it will get the job done and you do not have to search for special libraries.